# Install Git on Centos 6.2

Tags: linux, git, centos

I'm trying to install Git on my cloud server, where is running Centos6.2.
But running this command:

```
yum install git
```

this error block the installation process:

```
Error: Package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
```

Now, I see that inside /usr/lib64/ folder there are this files:

```
libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.1.1*
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.1.1*
libcurl.so.4.1.1*
```

Isn't possible to tell git to use libcurl.so.4.1.1 instead of libcurl.so.3?

Answer (score 4):

Just went through the same problem.
It's because it tries to install the centos 5 release: git-1.7.11.3-1.**el5**.rf.x86_64

To check, you can issue

```
yum list git
```

This showed me the el5 (wrong) package and el6 (correct) package.
Then select the el6 one which is called git.i686 and run :

```
yum install git.i686
```

I hope it will solve your issue or at least help you to find the correct package for your system!

**Correction**: installing git.i686 worked but didn't help to get git functional.
Finally got it by doing this:

```
yum remove rpmforge-release
yum install git
```

This removed the el5 version of rpmforge installed on my el6 system that was messing installation of GIT.